# Closed subset of a affine linear group

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $G\subseteq GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ a Zariski-closed linear subgroup and $X\subseteq G$ closed with $X*X\subseteq X$ and $e \in X$. Then $X$ is a subroup. I am not sure how to start here. I know that $X^{-1}$ is also closed and that $e\in X\cap X^{-1}$. Is that going to help me?

Thank you.

Comment: My idea would be to consider $Y = \{x \in X : x^{-1} \in X\}$. This is closed in $X$ since it is the preimage along the diagonal $X \to X \times X$ of $\{(x,y) \in X \times X : x * y=e\}$. So it is enough to show that $Y$ is dense.

Comment: Thank you. I am not quite sure how this works, what would your map $X\rightarrow X\times X$ exactly do? Greetings from Münster =)

Comment: Sorry, the diagonal was nonsense. $Y$ is closed since it is the preimage of $X \subseteq G$ under $X \hookrightarrow G \xrightarrow{\iota} G$. But the main problem is to show that $Y$ is dense. Perhaps this whole approach doesn't work that way. I'm not really familiar with algebraic groups. Hm, what about the implicit function theorem applied to the multiplication of $X$? I think this works, at least, for the corresponding statement about Lie groups.